TransformFeedback with instanced drawing
How does WebGL write data to a transform-feedback output when doing instanced drawing? Particularly, how does it decide on what index of the transform-feedback-buffer to write to when using instanced drawing?
Consider the following example:

I want to draw a lot of particles as rectangles (hence instanced drawing)
The position of each particle is determined by an offset attribute
That offset attribute should be updated for each draw via transform feedback

Setup
Here's some pseudo-code (full code available here):
Vertex shader:
#version 300 es
in vec2 rectVertex;
in vec2 offset;
out vec2 newOffset;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(rectVertex + offset, 0, 1);
  newOffset = offset + vec2(0.02);
}

Fragment shader:
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
  fragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

JS:

  const program = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader, ['newOffset']);
  const rectBuffer = createBuffer(rectData.flat()); // 6*2 entries
  const offsetBuffer1 = createBuffer(offsetData.flat()); // 100*2 entries
  const offsetBuffer2 = createBuffer(offsetData.flat()); // 100*2 entries

  const vao1 = createVao(
    {
      rectVertex: { buffer: rectBuffer, nrInstances: 0 },
      offset: { buffer: offsetBuffer1, nrInstances: 1 },
    },
    program
  );
  const tf1 = createTf({
    newOffset: offsetBuffer2,
  });

  const vao2 = createVao(
    {
      rectVertex: { buffer: rectBuffer, nrInstances: 0 },
      offset: { buffer: offsetBuffer2, nrInstances: 1 },
    },
    program
  );
  const tf2 = createTf({
    newOffset: offsetBuffer1,
  });

  drawInstanced({ program, vao: vao1, tf: tf1, nrInstances });

  drawInstanced({ program, vao: vao2, tf: tf2, nrInstances });



Observation
Chrome gives me a helpful error:
[.WebGL-0x11c00521400] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Not enough space in bound transform feedback buffers.

Why does that error occur?
I'm not quite sure... but here's my best guess, written in python pseudo-code:
import numpy as np

nrInstances = 5
nrVertices = 3

positionBuffer = {
    "data": np.array([[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [5,6], [6,7]], dtype=np.float32),
    "nrInstances": 1
}

# transform feedback output
positionNewBuffer = {
    "data": np.array([[0, 0]] * nrInstances * nrVertices, dtype=np.float32),
}


# my understanding of how webgl fetches data from instanced
# and non-instanced attributes:
def getDataIn(i, v, buffer):
    index = 0
    if "nrInstances" in buffer:
        # https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#nameddest=subsection.2.9
        # If an enabled vertex attribute array is instanced (it has a non-zero 
        # divisor), the element that is transferred to the GL, for
        # all vertices, is given by:
        # floor(instance / divisor)
        index = int(i / buffer["nrInstances"])   # independent of v!

    # non-instanced: same vertices used for all instances
    else:
        index = v                                # independent of i!

    data = buffer["data"][index]
    return data


# my understanding of how webgl places data in a transform-feedback buffer:
def setDataOut(value, i, v, buffer):
    # https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#nameddest=subsection.2.15.2
    # not sure how this is implemented when doing instanced drawing,
    # but here's my guess:
    indexOut = i * nrVertices + v
    buffer["data"][indexOut] = value


# draw call:
for i in range(nrInstances):
    for v in range(nrVertices):
        valPos = getDataIn(i, v, positionBuffer)
        newVal = valPos + 0.02
        setDataOut(newVal, i, v, positionNewBuffer)


The problem here is this:
While webgl expects the input-attribute position to have a buffer with nrInstances * 2 elements, it requires the output-transform-feedback buffer to have nrInstances * nrVertices * 2 elements.
Question
Is my suspicion correct? Is there a way to configure transform feedback in such a way that I can still combine transform feedback with instanced drawing?

One could circumvent this issue by splitting the work over two programs: one that does transform feedback with points, to obtain the new offset values, and a second one that does instanced drawing with rectangles. But I wonder if there is a more idiomatic solution. After all, instanced drawing and transform feedback work fine if you only do point drawing, so for consistency it would be nice to be able to do the same with triangles.
